# SQL Server workaround for execute as user=?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I inherited a very non-normalized SQL Server database.  The setup is such that every plant at this company has it's own schema within the database.  Inside each schema, there are a few important common tables that are the same structure and a few tables that are related to what products that specific plant makes.  The important thing though is that these common tables, all have their rows generated not via a regular INSERT statement but via stored procedures.  Here's where I run into my problem

The way things were done, is that these stored procedures would take the schema as one of the parameters and then execute as that user.  So after all the `DECLARE` statements there is a `execute as user = @Schema` statement, so that if I do `EXECUTE [dbo].[createRecord] 'SomePlant', 'otherArgs'`, it will do the insert statements against `SomePlant.someTable`.

Now, the company I am doing this work for, they want to get rid of all these local user accounts and only use a single AD account to connect the application to the database.  So now in our testing environment, all these stored procedures are failing with `Cannot execute as the database principal because the principal'SomePlant' does not exist, this type of principal cannot be impersonated, or you do not have permission.`

Is there any way I can easily make the rest of the stored procedure run it's queries against a specific schema, without `execute as user` since these local users that were associated with the schemas do not exist anymore and are going away, or is this going to require a re-writing of these stored procedures to not use this methodology at all?  If a full re-write is required I will probably end up doing them in python in my application but if there is some simple fix in SQL Server to get the same behavior with only a few lines, I am on a deadline and that would probably be preferable (also because I think but am not sure that other people use these stored procedures outside our application).

I am looking for suggestions because with my current knowledge, it seems like a re-write is unavoidable.  And if the re-write must be in SLQ due to applications outside the one I manage using the stored procedures, I don't see how else to do it except for converting a lot of stuff to dynamic sql and `execute sp_executesql` which is not ideal imo.

Comment: It seems like you should be combining all these tables in single tables, and adding a column that denotes what ever value the name of the schema previously represented. If access to data from other schemas needs to be implemented as well, then you can use Row Level Security (RLS) to do that.

Comment: Or give your new AD user rights over all schemas, then remove the execute as statements from all the SPs

Comment: How would they parametrise what schema they then access with that method, @JonathanWillcock (without dynamic SQL)?

Comment: The AD has rights over the whole schema, its the db owner for testing's sake but what Larnu said is exactly the issue.

@Larnu So you're saying normalize all the tables?  I would if the scope of this work included that but that would require a massive rewrite of the database and application logic as it stands now and that is not in scope for this job or doable before deadline.  Unless you're suggesting something else I don't understand?

Comment: That is exactly what i am suggesting, @BrianKarabinchak . If the requirement is to switch to a single user, then you need to switch to single tables, rather than (ab)use the default schema logic.

Comment: The schema is a string parameter of the stored procedure, and then the `execute as user=@schema` means the rest of the written queries get written against `parameterSchema.someTable`

Comment: @Larnu Good point. They would need a bunch of Ifs. So probably not practical (depending on the number of schemas)

Comment: Yea there's about 90 schemas so definitely not the right way to go.  So seems like my only options are normalizing all the tables, which would definitely be good for maintenance but be a lot more work than originally quoted, or to be rewriting more garbage schema specific queries inside my python app instead.

Comment: `execute as user=@schema` does this.  So they need to make a record for `somePlant2`, then `[dbo].[createRecord] 'somePlant2', 'otherArgs'` gets called, and the first thing that is done in the stored procedure is saying `execute as user='somePlant2'` which means all queries refer to that schema.

Comment: You aren't actually parametrising the schema there though, @BrianKarabinchak . What you're doing is parametrising the `USER` the SQL is run under, which as a result *changes* the default schema, and (presumably) your SQL *omits* the schema name when objects are referenced. So the default schema feature is (ab)used to use the "correct" object. Omitting the schema for objects is considered a [bad habit](https://sqlblog.org/2019/09/12/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix) by most anyway, so honestly, this only further cements that the design needs to change at a very fundamental level.

Comment: Yea no way can this thing be rewritten with 90ish different schemas.  I agree not using the schema and using the user like this is just abusing the default schema.  I would have never done this but now its my mess to work with.  I have my meeting with the customer soon to discuss.  Hopefully either they are ok with my normalizing of the databases or  if not (since they have a bunch of other data transfers setup with these separate schemas) at least rewriting it in python.

Thank you for all the input you confirmed my suspicions.

Answer (score 2):

Given the current state (i.e. multiple users each having a different default schema) and the requirement to move to a common login, I would suggest using loginless users within the database that have the same permissions as the existing ones and granting impersonate access to the common login. It'd look something like this:

```sql
use yourDb;

create user appUser1 without login with default_schema schema1;
/* migrate permissions for existing schema1 user to appUser1 here */
grant impersonate on user::appUser1 to actualAppLogin;

create user appUser2 without login with default_schema schema2;
/* migrate permissions for existing schema2 user to appUser2 here */
grant impersonate on user::appUser2 to actualAppLogin;

/* et cetera */
```

This should allow all of the extant `execute as user = @Schema;` statements that are in the code to Just Work™ for the new AD-based login.

Comment: Interesting, I will try this out later.  Do these users cease to exist after the stored procedure finishes?  Do they populate the "Security" folder with these logins?  I have a second meeting now on Monday to discuss how we can resolve the issue, I will bring this up as an option.  I appreciate you may have found a way to save me a lot of work.

Comment: The "without login" clause means that these users can't be used to authenticate either at the server or database (in the case of contained databases) level. They'll still show up as users in the database's user folder and also in the sys.database_principals DMV.

Comment: I'm finally working on this in a dev version fo the SQL Cluster.  The SQL Server cluster has my database and many others.  Underneath my database Security\Users folder there is already a user there with the schema names.  So when I try `USE MyDB;` and create my user,  I get an error that that user already exists and is the principal owner of the that schema.